# JS defineProperty setter doesn't triggered

Tags: javascript, defineproperty

Q1: Can someone explain how to trigger setter in defineProperty, using it via function by this way?

Q2: How to get last key in setter?

[fiddle is here](https://jsfiddle.net/2rbor3qr/)

```
function test(root) {

  Object.defineProperty(this, 'subtree', {
    get: function() {
      console.log("get");
      return root.subtree;
    },
    set: function(value) { //doesn't triggered
      console.log("set");
      root.subtree = value;
    }
  });

}

var demo = new test({
    subtree: {
        state: null,
        test: 1
    }
});

console.log("START", demo.subtree);

demo.subtree.state = 13; // doesn't triggered setter, but change object

console.log("END", demo.subtree);
```

Comment: You can use get set functions, like demo.subtree.set({ state: 13, test: 1 }).


To get key in setter use a object to store every time setter is fired.

Comment: Danish, result: Uncaught TypeError: demo.subtree.set is not a function. Any ideas?

Comment: [Read the manual please](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set). If you don't find any answer, come back.

Comment: var person = { firstName: 'Jimmy', lastName: 'Smith', get fullName() { return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName; }, set fullName (name) { var words = name.toString().split(' '); this.firstName = words[0] || ''; this.lastName = words[1] || ''; } } person.fullName = 'Jack Franklin'; console.log(person.firstName); // Jack console.log(person.lastName) // Franklin


Try the above example..

Comment: @PiotrKocia, i readed that also - [defineProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty), and I really don't understand why [that](https://jsfiddle.net/tawvwpua/6/) setter works and why [that](https://jsfiddle.net/uat08xh6/7/) setter doesn't.

Comment: @Danish, ok but how to wrap it in function to call it in declaring object? And how to make it work without putting subkey name in it?

Comment: Try `demo.subtree = {state: 13}` to see your setter at work.

Comment: @Bergi, thx it's worked, and now by Object.keys(value) i can get key name. But is there a way to make it works by calling it in this way: demo.subtree.state = 13?

Comment: @Romario For that you need to make `.state` of the `subtree` object a setter/getter property.

Comment: @Bergi, example, please?

Comment: @Romario You will need to return an object from `get state` that is built similar to `new test()`

Answer (score 0):

To make it simpler, this code

```
let variable = null;
let obj = {
    set variable(value) {
        variable = value;
    }
    get variable() {
        return variable;
    }
};

obj.variable = {a: 5};
console.log(obj.variable);
```

does exactly the same thing as this one

```
let variable = null;
let obj = {
    setVariable(value) {
        variable = value;
    }
    getVariable() {
        return variable;
    }
};

obj.setVariable({a: 5}); // equivalent to obj.variable = {a: 5}
console.log(obj.getVariable()); // equivalent to obj.variable
```

but the latter clearly shows what's going on.

We want to access `a` and set it to some value

```
console.log(obj.getVariable().a); // get a
obj.getVariable().a = 6; // set a!
```

Notice that we don't call `setVariable` to set `a`'s value!!! This is exactly what happens in your code. You get `subtree` and set `state` to `13`. To call setter, you do the following

```
obj.setVariable({a: 6});
obj.variable = {a: 6}; // getter/setter example
demo.subtree = {state: 13}; // your code
```

[This](https://jsfiddle.net/tawvwpua/6/) and [this](https://jsfiddle.net/uat08xh6/7/) (linked by you) present how scopes and capturing work, so you should get your hands on some book that covers all those things (or browse SO, there are (probably) plenty of questions about that).

Comment: Ie, there is no way to run setter by 'tree.subtree = val'? Then how it works in vue.js?

Comment: @Romario what do you mean by `tree.subtree = val`? Full code sample maybe?

Comment: Piotr, there is no full code, only [fiddle from topic](https://jsfiddle.net/2rbor3qr/). Just trying to understand how reactive JS frameworks works and how to catch changes in object, and then do some magic with it.

Comment: Hahaha... You should have called the question "How do frameworks observe objects". Anyway, they do some magic inside (such as creating getters/setters for each property/function/whatever to notify appropriate observers). Notice that they don't know about things you don't tell them you did. You should read about *observer pattern* and write your own (simple!) observer. You should also read [vue's reactivity docs](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html) (vue or any other framework) to learn how such pattern looks from the "outside".

Comment: Piotr, thx for your attention, but 'hahaha' what? I'm not programmer, it's my hobby. I've read that article before creating topic and seen 'Vue will walk through all of its properties and convert them to getter/setters using Object.defineProperty', then i've read about it on MDN, then tried some code and stucked with setter. As result i've created this topic. Main point of my question was "how to make setter works in this way", and under "this way" i  meant calling a function with setter/getter inside while declaring an object. Not just setter/getter of object.